# PowerBi report embedding in Angular Web Application

Tags: angular, web-applications, powerbi, azure-active-directory

I have an angular web application which will be authenticated using Azure AD. After login, in some pages I would like to show some reports using PowerBi. The data in the reports will be logged-in user specific data.

I have created PowerBi reports in PowerBi desktop. The report is loaded from Web API. Web api is protected using Azure AD. To create the report, I copied a token from Web application and given it in the powerbi desktop to hit the web api I could retrieve the data from api.
I have parameterized the power bi report to accept AD token from angular web application so that while embedding the report, angular will pass AD token to powerbi and powerbi can retrieve this token and can call web api. This was my plan. I published this report and embedded in angular application as well.

To get embedding token I followed below steps.
First, Retrieved an access token using client credential flow inputting client-id and client-secret. And this access token again passed to powerbi rest api for the specific report to generate the powerbi report token. and using this token and report id and group id, I could load the powerbi report in ui.

Now my problem is I have to show the latest data in the report each time when the user seeing the report. Now I only I really understood the powerbi report data model will be refrshed in a scheduled way if we do not need manual intervention. But here I cant schedule it because I need the data for the logged-in user in the web.

Can anyone suggest the correct way I should follow.